# Format each list entry with name JSON

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to format a List object to JSON in a specific way:

...

```
{
    "MyList": [
        "Entry": {
           "Id": "1000",
           "Name" : "Billy"
        }
    ]
}
```

...

My problem is that I can't get the "Entry" property name to be written per item in the list.

Here's my C# code:

Entry.cs

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Entry
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

List.cs

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class MyList
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        List<Entry> List = new List<Entry>();

        public void Add(Entry param) {
            List.Add(param);
        }
    }
```

TestController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GrabarMarcacion([FromBody] JObject data)
    {
        MyList lst = new MyList();
        lst.Add(new Entry{Id="1000", Name="Billy"});
        return Ok(lst);
    }
```

I'm sorry I'm new to JSON and REST, is it even possible to do what I ask? so far I always get something like:

```
{
    "List": {
        {
            "ID": "1000",
            "Name" : "Billy"
        },
        {
                    "ID": "1001",
            "Name" : "Bob"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, intended Json doesn't look valid Json format. Please ensure it has a valid format

Comment: As @AnuViswan said you can't really generate invalid JSON with JSON serializer. Either change your expectations to valid JSON or use regular text operations to construct whatever format you like (but don't call it JSON and don't expect anyone to be able to parse it as such). Please [edit] post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used c# but try for Entry.cs :

```cs
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Entry
  {
  [JsonProperty]
  public object Entry { get; set; }
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tryed that, it says is not valid for this declaration type..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want `Entry` property name for every item in the list. The simplest way to do this would be by making it a `Dictionary`:

Renamed `Entry.cs` to `EntryModel.cs`

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class EntryModel
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Entry { get; set; }
}
```

In `List.cs`, change the property to `MyList`. This requires a change to the class name.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyListModel
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<EntryModel> MyList { get; set; } = new List<EntryModel>();
}
```

Now in your `TestController.cs`, you may use:

```
MyListModel lst = new MyListModel();
lst.MyList.Add(new EntryModel 
{
    Entry = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Id", "1000" }, { "Name", "Billy" } }
});

lst.MyList.Add(new EntryModel
{
    Entry = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "Id", "3000" }, {"Name", "ABC" } }
});
```

This gives the following JSON:

```
{
  "MyList": [
    {
      "Entry": {
        "Id": "1000",
        "Name": "Billy"
      }
    },
    {
      "Entry": {
        "Id": "3000",
        "Name": "ABC"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I needed, but I was able to solve my problem by wrapping my Entry class inside another class. Then, I declared a list of that wrapper class and it ended up working as I wanted. This gave me the idea, so thank you sir